# how to clear the winsock cached http redirects (301 permanently moved)

Tags: http, redirect, caching, winsock

I'm using winsock to send http requests to internet. I discovered that something in the system on my computer caches http 301 permanently moved responses. So if I send a GET request for a certain URL it returns an old response without sending anything out onto the web. Problem, because the cached response is faulty. I want to clear the cache, but don't even know who is doing the caching.

I know how to clear this cache in my browser. Also, when I use wininet instead of winsock there is no problem. Where is the cache for winsock and how do I clear it?

EDIT: Andreas' response below occasions some remarks. My program is running as a proxy on localhost, receiving requests from Firefox and sending them out onto the web. So the requests are set up by Firefox and the host header is always there. The reason I think this has something to do with winsock on my own computer is that Firefox will get the page all right if I don't use my proxy server. No 301 response then. But Firefox had this problem too (without proxy) until I cleared its history (forget about this site). That's why I think it must be a winsock cache problem.

Since Firefox succeeds (without proxy) when its cache is cleared it cannot be my ISP doing the caching. Note that the request sent out is identical whether going through my proxy or not. I don't change anything. Also, as I said, wininet works.

I agree that winsock knows nothing about http. Yet, there seems to be something between winsock and the web having a cache function. What other explanation can there be? My proxy works all right with many other sites, but on a few ones I get this 301 permanently moved reponse with a faulty location header. How can I find out more about what's going on?

Comment: You are saying that you have this problem not just with one site, but with several sites? It is more than one physical HTTP server that causes you to get a HTTP 301 response? Or is it maybe the same physical server and just a different [virtual server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_hosting)?

Comment: Did you code this proxy program yourself or are you just using someone else's program? If you coded it yourself, what exactly does your proxy program do? Does it just forward everything it receives as-is from one TCP connection to the other TCP connection? Or does ist change the contents in some way? Either way, I don't see any opportunity for caching, except by a [transparent proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server#Transparent_proxy). Therefore, I suspect a bug in your program as the cause, assuming that you wrote it yourself.

Comment: Assuming that you wrote the proxy program yourself, it may help if your program generated a log file of everything it receives and everything it sends successfully(!) (not unsuccessfully attempts to send). This information could be helpful in diagnosing the problem. For example, it should log exactly how many bytes the Winsock `send` function actually sent (not how much it tried to send) and whether the send was successful. Logging the actual contents could also be helpful.

Comment: Yes, several sites cause this problem and I now suspect that it's a bug in some servers or subservers. Not a cache problem after all. As far as I remember all the problem sites use a PHP subserver. My hypothesis right now is that if I do GET http://www.example.com the error takes effect, but if I do GET / it works all right. I'll test this as soon as possible. When Firefox succeeds it always does the latter, as far as I remember. But for some reason it always sends the former to my proxy.

Comment: Yes I wrote the proxy program myself. It does what a proxy is supposed to do. It does nothing but forward requests and responses. My purpose, though, is to filter and to proxy through other hops not possessing full proxy capabiliy, but this hasn't been implemented yet. If there is a bug in my program how can it work just fine with the large majority of sites?

Comment: I had the proxy program print the requests and responses. There is nothing wrong with the requests and I succeed in sending them. I also succeed in receiving the responses. But some of them are 301 ones as explained. And in those responses the location header contains a faulty value which looks like this: http://www.example.comhttp/www.example.com .  Yes almost a double url but notice the missing :/ in the last one. I print the response raw so it's not my parsing that is wrong. Also, when I forward the response to the Firefox without parsing the same faulty url turns up on the address bar.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200723/discussion-between-andreas-wenzel-and-henrik4).

Answer (score 2):

Winsock does not cache web pages. It knows nothing about HTTP, so it cannot cache HTTP responses.

If you are indeed only using Winsock to send an HTTP request, and if you are doing this directly (not over a proxy), then it must be a [transparent proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server#Transparent_proxy) that is caching the requests. Some ISPs use them and this often causes technical trouble.

However, I am not convinced that this is a caching issue. If you are using Winsock to send an HTTP request, I suspect that it is more likely that there is something wrong with your HTTP request. For example, nowadays, many servers use virtual hosting and therefore require the client to send the "Host" field in the HTTP header, so that the request can be assigned to the correct virtual server. If you don't do this, you will be served by the wrong virtual server. This could be the reason you are receiving a HTTP 301 permanently moved response and it could also be why it works with WinInet (because it sends a correct "Host" header field).

However, this contradicts your claim that sending a GET request for a certain URL does not send anything out to the internet. What exactly makes you think that this is the case? Are you using a network packet sniffer?

Comment: Regardless of virtual hosting, the `Host` header is *required* in all HTTP 1.1 requests, but is *optional* in HTTP 1.0 requests.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found it now. It's not a cache problem after all. There is a bug in some servers or subservers. Some common server frameworks like PHP. The bug is this: If I request the root document of the site with full url (GET http://example.com) then it returns a 301 permanently moved response with faulty location header. If I request it with GET / then it works and I get that document returned with 200 OK status.

So what I do now is to check whether the target is an absolute url. If so I check whether the path is empty. If it is I change the target to /.

Now it works and I don't get any more 301 responses.

Comment: According to [section 5 of RFC 2616](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec5.html), all HTTP/1.1 servers "MUST accept the absoluteURI form in requests, even though HTTP/1.1 clients will only generate them in requests to proxies". Therefore, it appears to indeed be a bug, assuming that the HTTP request complies with HTTP/1.1. Did you specify an HTTP version in the request? if not, then you are using HTTP/0.9 (which I believe does not support absoluteURIs).

Comment: Interesting info. I didn't know that clients only generate them when working through proxies. Yes, it's HTTP/1.1 and I do specify that: GET http://example.com HTTP/1.1 . This must be the reason why the bug rarely makes itself felt. Not many people go through proxies, and maybe standard proxies change the target like I do now. So the bug is hard to discover.